# Does Inno Setup "external" clause take care of both loading and uploading?

Tags: dll, inno-setup, pascalscript

Does the `external` clause take care of both loading and unloading (`LoadDLL/UnloadDLL`). Or do I still have to unload DLLs manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `external` directive, the DLLs are not unloaded at all. In general, there's no reason to. With the `external` directive, the assumption is that you want to use the DLLs throughout the lifetime of the installer process. There's no clear point where Inno Setup can safely assume that it can unload the DLLs. So they get unloaded automatically by the system, once Inno Setup installer process exits.

Usually the only case, where you need to unload the DLL is a use of your *custom* DLL in the uninstaller, if you want to delete (uninstall) the DLL afterwards. For that use the [`UnloadDLL` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_unloaddll).

Comment: And If I have a DLL with dependencies do I have to `UnloadDLL` all the dependent DLLs in the uninstaller?

Comment: @JConstantine I do not know.